# reading json data from variable instead of file in python

Tags: json, python-2.7, jboss-cli

I'm creating a python script to extract values from `jboss-cli.sh` which by default return output in below format:

```
    {
        "outcome" => "success",
        "result" => {
            "ActiveCount" => "0",
            "AvailableCount" => "0",
            "AverageBlockingTime" => "0",
            "AverageCreationTime" => "0",
            "CreatedCount" => "0",
            "DestroyedCount" => "0",
            "InUseCount" => "0",
            "MaxCreationTime" => "0",
            "MaxUsedCount" => "0",
            "MaxWaitCount" => "0",
            "MaxWaitTime" => "0",
            "TimedOut" => "0",
            "TotalBlockingTime" => "0",
            "TotalCreationTime" => "0",
            "statistics-enabled" => false
        }
    }
```

Now i'm converting this to JSON format using below code:

`from jbossply.jbossparser import JbossParser
parser = JbossParser()
print(parser.parse(OUT))`

so it is giving output as:

`{u'outcome': u'success', u'result': {u'AverageBlockingTime': u'0', u'AvailableCount': u'0', u'statistics-enabled': False, u'MaxCreationTime': u'0', u'MaxUsedCount': u'0', u'CreatedCount': u'0', u'MaxWaitCount': u'0', u'TimedOut': u'0', u'InUseCount': u'0', u'ActiveCount': u'0', u'TotalBlockingTime': u'0', u'DestroyedCount': u'0', u'AverageCreationTime': u'0', u'TotalCreationTime': u'0', u'MaxWaitTime': u'0'}}`

Now how to extract "AvailableCount" out of it. Tried json.load but not working.

Comment: What version of WildFly or JBoss EAP are you using?

Comment: I ask because in WildFly there is now an option you can add to the `jboss-cli.xml` to allow the output to be JSON. https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-3363

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer by myself, parsed json to a variable and extracted result like beow:

`parser = JbossParser()
data=(parser.parse(OUT))
TOTAL_CN=(data["result"]["AvailableCount"])`

Comment: good, i din't download your code so I had to do json.dump nd then load!

Answer (score 2):

Try this!

```
from jbossply.jbossparser import JbossParser
import json

parser = JbossParser()
parser_out = parser.parse(OUT)
json_dump = json.dump(parser_out)
json_load = json.loads(json_dump)
print json_load['result']['AvailableCount']
# op 0
```